# why I get error from get request when i try to get last coins

Tags: swift, coinmarketcap

when I try to make get request with https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/cryptocurrency/info?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=key.
I get an error msg - value must contain at least one of [id, symbol, slug, address]
But from what I understand I can get 100 in a straight.
I would love to understand where I am wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check the api docs: https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV2CryptocurrencyInfo

You simply need to add an additional query parameter `...info?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=key&id=1`. You are not providing any information about what you want specific crypto info you want.

Comment: because I want not just one. if I want all the details of 100 coins?

Comment: @Hello422, then you need to request a different endpoint, if that is even an option. Again, read the docs. You should also read this: https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2017fa/thoughtful.html